# Can't run MYSQL container using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a MYSQL container for my project using docker-compose.

When I use the following command, everything works fine:

> docker run --name mysql-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest

But when I built this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-db:
    container_name: mysql-db
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE='crm'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

The command:

> docker-compose up --build

I got this message error:

> mysql-db        | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' ->
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' mysql-db        | Warning: Unable to
> load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
> mysql-db        | Warning: Unable to load
> '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it. mysql-db
> | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time
> zone. Skipping it. mysql-db        | Warning: Unable to load
> '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it. mysql-db
> | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time
> zone. Skipping it. mysql-db        | ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You
> have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''' at
> line 1 mysql-db exited with code 1

I also notice that there is this log right here says that I didn't set the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD although I've already declared that

> mysql-db        | 2023-01-10T07:29:03.521464Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453]
> [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please
> consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

I'm extremely new to docker so hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Have you tried this solution ? : https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/229

Comment: @shubham I don't think so, above is all the config i have in the docker-compose file

Comment: @SelVazi I think the problem have something to do with the line: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''' at line 1

Comment: Can you share your queries ?

Comment: @SelVazi I haven't run any queries yet :( the container got that error while I tried to build the docker-compose file, this is the command: docker-compose up --build

Comment: The single quotes in the `environment:` values will be included as part of the value – the value of `$MYSQL_DATABASE` will be `'crm'`, including the quotes – and this might be throwing off the database setup.  Does removing these single quotes help?

Comment: Also see similar answers I've written [here](/a/74420754) and [here](/a/73703867).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce with your compose file locally on my machine and it resulted into `same error`.

Only solution for this problem currently lies in the link shared by `@SelVazi`. We would need to build your custom mysql image and then use that to create mysql container.

### Here is an example

#### Create a Dockerfile

I picked mysql image with tag 8 as I am running on Mac M1.

```
FROM mysql:8.0.31-debian

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y tzdata \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

#### Create Docker Compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-local:
    build: .
    image: mysql-local:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    container_name: mysql-local
    # I am running on Mac M1 Apple Silicon, You might not need it.
    platform: linux/x86_64
  mysql-db:
    container_name: mysql-db
    image: mysql-local:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql-local
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE='crm'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

#### Run compose file

```
docker-compose -f mysql-compose.yaml up --build
```